# Select Outlook Folder With Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I'm trying to bypass having to select the folder I want and just tell Excel to go ahead and count the "Inbox"

```
Sub Get_Emails()

Dim OLF As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim EmailItemCount As Long

Set OLF = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder
EmailItemCount = OLF.Items.Count

Range("A1") = EmailItemCount

Set OLF = Nothing

Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub
```

Does anyone know how I can just get the count without having to select the folder? Excel VBA should just automatically go into the "Inbox" and give me my count.

Note: You have to go to Tools > References > and select "Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library" in order for this macro to work.

Comment: See comment on your duplicate question where the code should work if you do not Set objnSpace = Nothing before trying to use it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43637311/how-to-specify-nested-folder-in-outlook-using-excel-vba

Answer (score 3):

Here is something that works:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopFoldersInInbox()

    Dim ns              As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim myfolder        As Outlook.Folder
    Dim mysubfolder     As Outlook.Folder

    Set ns = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set myfolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    For Each mysubfolder In myfolder.Folders
        Debug.Print mysubfolder.name
        Debug.Print mysubfolder.Items.Count
    Next mysubfolder

End Sub
```

With some [credits here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?39677-Solved-Looping-through-Inbox-to-find-all-Sub-Folders). It is with early binding. Thus, if you press the dot in `ns` or `mysubfolder` you will see the properties and the actions they have:
[image]

Here is the late binding, thus you do not need to refer to the Outlook Library explicitly and the code would work on more users:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopFoldersInInbox()

    Dim ns                  As Object
    Dim objFolder           As Object
    Dim objSubfolder        As Object

    Set ns = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(6) ' 6 is equal to olFolderInbox

    For Each objSubfolder In objFolder.Folders
        Debug.Print objSubfolder.name
        Debug.Print objSubfolder.Items.Count
    Next objSubfolder

End Sub
```

In this late binding, I have used `6` in stead of `olFolderInbox`.

Edit:
If you want the results in the cells, use this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopFoldersInInbox()

    Dim ns                  As Object
    Dim objFolder           As Object
    Dim objSubfolder        As Object
    Dim lngCounter          As Long

    Set ns = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(6) ' 6 is equal to olFolderInbox

    For Each objSubfolder In objFolder.Folders
        With ActiveSheet
            lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
            .Cells(lngCounter, 1) = objSubfolder.Name
            .Cells(lngCounter, 2) = objSubfolder.Items.Count
        End With

        Debug.Print objSubfolder.Name
        Debug.Print objSubfolder.Items.Count

    Next objSubfolder

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Vityata but this did not work for me. Your code does not fill in a Range on the excel worksheet "Sheet 1". I'd like to be able to specify "Inbox", "Outbod", "Drafts", etc...

Comment: That's really great Vityata, you're the man! One more question. How do you specify a specific folder within a subfolder? This code works Set objFolder = ns.Folders("NoctalkSW").Folders("Inbox"). But, this code does not Set objFolder = ns.Folders("NoctalkSW").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Completed"). Any idea why not? I just want to specify the specify folder.

Comment: I don't really appreciate your comment of "read the first 100 pages of any VBA book." Vityana. Keep it positive, there's no need for that.

Comment: @MarkS - sry, I am telling it with my best feelings, I don't want to make you feel bad or similar. But in general, in the first 100 pages of any VBA book you would find how to refer to cells/ranges/active sheets. If you feel offended - I will delete it.

Comment: That's okay, don't worry about it Vityata. Do you know how to specify only olNoFlag items in the folder with your looped code? I am unable to get the code to return the date/time for just the No Flag items. I'm trying to use .Cells(lngCounter, 3) = objSubfolder.olNoFlag.Items.GetLast.ReceivedTime but it's not working. Help!

Answer (score 1):

The below is more of what I am looking for but Vityana's code works very well too. It all depends on what you need. I would like to specify a folder within the "Inbox" but am currently unable to. This only gets the count for the "Inbox" but there are folders nested under the "Inbox" folder that I am unable to specify. Anyone know how to do that?

```
Sub HowManyEmails()
Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As Object
Dim EmailCount As Integer
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

On Error Resume Next
Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders("Joe.L.Smo@company.com").Folders("Inbox")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
MsgBox "No such folder."
Exit Sub
End If

EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objnSpace = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing

[B2].Value = EmailCount

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just "continue the specification".

You had:

```
Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders("Joe.L.Smo@company.com").Folders("Inbox")
```

To get -for example- the content of the subfolder Temp under the Inbox, specify:

```
Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders("Joe.L.Smo@company.com").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Temp")
```

Hope this helps