# How to specify nested folder in Outlook using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I need help specifying a nested folder in Outlook using Excel VBA. I will post the code I'm using below.

I'm able to specify the "Inbox" folder but when I try and specify a folder that is within the "Inbox" folder, the code comes back with the "No such folder" message.

Does anyone know why this is happening to me? If so, how can I fix it?

```
Option Explicit
Sub HowManyEmails()
    Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As Object
    Dim EmailCount As Integer
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders("NoctalkSW").Folders("Inbox")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        MsgBox "No such folder."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objnSpace = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing

    [B2].Value = EmailCount

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objFolder = 
    objnSpace.Folders("NoctalkSW").Folders("Inbox").Folders("COMPLETED")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        MsgBox "No such folder."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objnSpace = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing

    [B3].Value = EmailCount

End Sub
```

Comment: No, that doesn't help me. I need to specify a nested folder under the "Inbox" folder. I'm asking how you specify the hierarchy of Outlook folders with Excel VBA.

Comment: You have Set objnSpace = Nothing then try to use objnSpace later

Comment: Can you explain little more to what your trying to do in your code?

Comment: This line of code works: Set objFolder = **objnSpace.Folders("NoctalkSW").Folders("Inbox")** but this line of code does NOT work **objnSpace.Folders("NoctalkSW").Folders("Inbox").Folders("COMPLETED")**. When I try and access a folder lower then the second level of Outlook, the code returns the "No such folder" message. Does that make more sense?

Comment: One more quick question that I forgot to ask, are you working on your default inbox or shared inbox?

Comment: I'm working in a Shared Mailbox named NoctalkSW. To simulate what I'm doing here, you can use a Shared Mailbox called "SharedTest1", then in the "Inbox" of that folder, create another folder called "Completed". How can we get a count from the "completed" folder? That's the trouble I'm having. My code accesses the "Inbox" folder, but when I try and access a folder in the "Completed" folder, it comes back with "No such folder". Hope this makes more sense now.

Comment: If you found Eugene's answer successful with the removal of `Set objNamespace = Nothing` consider accepting, to remove the question from unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to debug the code? Anyway, try to use the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub HowManyEmails() 
 Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As Object
 Dim EmailCount As Integer
 Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

 On Error Resume Next
 Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders("NoctalkSW").Folders("Inbox")
 If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  Err.Clear
  MsgBox "No such folder."
  Exit Sub
 End If

 EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count
 Set objFolder = Nothing
 Set objOutlook = Nothing

 [B2].Value = EmailCount

 On Error Resume Next
 Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders("NoctalkSW").Folders("Inbox").Folders("COMPLETED")
 If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  Err.Clear
  MsgBox "No such folder."
  Exit Sub
 End If

 EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count
 Set objFolder = Nothing
 Set objnSpace = Nothing
 Set objOutlook = Nothing

 [B3].Value = EmailCount
End Sub
```

Also you may try to iterate over folders, see [How to: Enumerate Folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184607.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: The code does not need to be debugged because it works until I try and specify a folder under the "Inbox" folder. Like I said above, when I try and do that it gives me the "No such folder" message because it doesn't know what folder I'm talking about. I'll try this but I have to say that this just looks like you re-pasted my code from up top. What's the difference here? I don't see it.

Comment: The first instance of Set objnSpace = Nothing was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

*If you wanna access shared Inbox and subfolder then Work with **[GetSharedDefaultFolder Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220116%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)***

> *<sub>**[GetSharedDefaultFolder Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220116%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)** Returns a MAPIFolder object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders.</sub>*
>
> ---

*Code Example*

```
Option Explicit
Const olFolderInbox = 6
Sub HowManyEmails()
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olNs As Object
    Dim Inbox As Object
    Dim SubFolder As Object
    Dim Recip As Object

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Recip = olNs.CreateRecipient("0m3r@email.com") ' Share address
        Recip.Resolve
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(Recip, olFolderInbox) ' Inbox

    [B2].Value = Inbox.Items.Count

    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("COMPLETED") ' subfolder

    [B3].Value = SubFolder.Items.Count

    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set Recip = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate your attempt at solving this 0m3r. Your code was unable to execute. It stopped on the line where it says '[B3].Value = SubFolder.Items.Count' with the error message of "Run-time error '-2147221241 (80040107)': The operation failed."

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code @MarkS that error could be the Exchange cached mode \ or slow connection- Try looking at your advanced additional mailboxes: Cached Exchange mode settings.

Comment: No, it's not working. I tried. The solution I'm using is from this page. It pulls over all the email counts from every folder into Excel. Then I pull what I need over from the worksheet with the folder count to the other worksheet I have. See this code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43613635/5227322