# How to move email to a folder inside a folder?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to move emails that match existing patterns.

How do I move mail to a folder inside a folder? e.g. designteam>mike or designteam>sandy

I copied this. I struggle to understand what Tabs is doing. Is it just storing the number of tabs?

At some point in this can I store the path to the folder?

```vb
Public Sub GetListOfFolders()
    On Error GoTo On_Error

    Dim Session As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Report As String
    Dim Folders As Outlook.Folders
    Dim Folder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim reply As Integer

    Set Session = Application.Session

    Set Folders = Session.Folders

    For Each Folder In Folders
        Call RecurseFolders(Folder, vbTab, Report)
    Next
    Dim retValue As Boolean
    Debug.Print (Report)

Exiting:
        Set Session = Nothing
        Exit Sub
On_Error:
    MsgBox "error=" & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    Resume Exiting

End Sub


Private Sub RecurseFolders(CurrentFolder As Outlook.Folder, Tabs, Report As String)
    Dim Table As Outlook.Table
    Dim Row As Outlook.Row
    Dim rowValues() As Variant
    Dim SubFolders As Outlook.Folders
    Dim SubFolder As Outlook.Folder

    Report = Report & Tabs & CurrentFolder.Name & vbCrLf

    Set SubFolders = CurrentFolder.Folders
    For Each SubFolder In SubFolders
        Call RecurseFolders(SubFolder, Tabs & vbTab, Report)
    Next SubFolder

End Sub
```

Comment: This code is designed to create an indented list of all the folders to which you have access.  Look at your folder pane.  The name of the store (the file on disc that holds emails, task, etc.) is against the left edge.  The folders within the store are indented by one tab.  The folders within those folders are indented by two tabs.  The folders within those folders are indented by three tabs.  This code creates a string that looks like your folder pane.  So `Tabs` specifies the current level of indenting.

Comment: Do you know what recursion is?  This code will be unintelligible unless you do.

Comment: What do you mean by “analyses … moves emails to match existing patterns”?  Do you intend to identify that most emails from John Doe are in folder “xxx\yyy\DoeJohn” and then move any other emails from John to the same folder?  I might want to file my new emails every day but I would not want to perform the analysis every day.  Also I would not want to file a new email unless I had answered it or marked it as processed.  Are you still exploring your options or do you have a detailed specification of your requirement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify nested folder in Outlook using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43637311/how-to-specify-nested-folder-in-outlook-using-excel-vba)

Comment: Yes, I understand recursion. With regard to the tabs I understand the output has tabs in it but I don't see any incrementing of tabs or a tabs variable so I guess it's an innate property being accessed.

Comment: With regard to function your last comment is spot on.

Comment: The nested calls of `RecurseFolders` specify `Tabs & vbTab` so every time it goes down a level, an extra vbTab is added.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know where the folders are there is no need to search for them.

With the designteam folder directly under the inbox. Adjust as applicable.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub moveToSubfolder()

Dim olInbox As Folder
Dim desTeamFolder As Folder
Dim mikeFolder As Folder
Dim sandyFolder As Folder

Dim currItem As Object

Set olInbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Set desTeamFolder = olInbox.Folders("designteam")

With desTeamFolder
    Set mikeFolder = .Folders("mike")
    Set sandyFolder = .Folders("sandy")
End With

Set currItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

If currItem.Class = olMail Then
    If InStr(currItem.Subject, "mike pattern") Then
        currItem.Move mikeFolder
    ElseIf InStr(currItem.Subject, "sandy pattern") Then
        currItem.Move sandyFolder
    Else
        Debug.Print "no match"
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My total answer exceeds Stack overflow's limit of 30,000 characters so I have split it into two.  This part includes all the explanatory text and some of the code.  The second part includes the remaining code.  A comment in italics in the middle of the first part shows where the second part belongs.

The code below is work-in-progress rather than a polished solution but includes some macros that may be immediately useful and I believe it includes all the snippets you need for your own solution.

I was a little ahead of you in deciding I needed to rearrange my Outlook stores and folders.  I had reached the stage of identifying the scale of the problem when I saw your question.  I have added a macro that moves selected emails.  This shows how to find source and destination folders and to move emails from one to the other.  This routine is not terribly useful for me because I have too many emails of which none are in the right folder but it ensures that everything I think you need is here.

This code is designed for an Excel workbook.  I knew I would want to store data in a worksheet so I would need to use both Excel and Outlook VBA.  It is possible for Outlook to push data to Excel or for Excel to pull data from Outlook.  I have gone for pull since I was confident I would need some Excel only macros and I prefer all code for a single problem to be in one place.

You will need to create a macro-enabled workbook.  This workbook must contain a worksheet named “Emails” and must reference "Microsoft Outlook n.nn Object Library" where "n.nn" depends on the version of Outlook used.

You will need to create a user form within that workbook.  If you are not familiar with user forms, search for “vba create userform” and you will find many tutorials.  My user form only uses label controls and has no code within it so it is as easy as it gets.

I use this user form to report progress.  On my system (with over 13,000 emails) some of my macros take several minutes. I hate programs that say “This may take from a few minutes to several hours” and then go quiet until they have finished.  I want to know that the program is doing something.  My user form looks like:

[image: Progress user form]

Do not worry about matching the text; it is there to help align the labels.  There is one label that runs across the top of the form and then two rows of four labels.  I have coloured my labels so you can see their size.  You must match my names:

```
Form:        frmProgress
First row:   lblMsg
Second row:  lblFldrName  lblFldrCrnt  lblFldrOf  lblFldrMax
Third row:   lblItemName  lblItemCrnt  lblItemOf  lblItemMax
```

On my form, the text in lblFldrName, lblFldrCrnt, lblItemName and lblItemCrnt is right-aligned.  I believe this improves the appearance but it is not important.

I use Excel’s PERSONAL.XLSB as a library of subs and functions.  Some routines are Excel only, some are for any version of VBA and some are for other Office products such as Outlook.  The following function comes from a module I name “LibOutlook”:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function GetFldrRef(ByRef AppOut As Outlook.Application, _
                           ByVal FldrName As String, _
                           ByVal Create As Boolean, ByRef ErrMsg As String, _
                           Optional ByVal Sep As String = "\") As Outlook.Folder

  ' Returns reference to the Outlook folder named FldrName
  ' Returns Nothing if:
  '    the store cannot be found
  '    the folder cannot be found and Create is False

  ' AppOut    Open copy of Outlook
  ' FldrName  The full name of the folder in the format:
  '             StoreName\Folder1\Folder2\...
  ' Create    If True, the folder will be created if it does not exist.
  '           Note, the store must exist. This routine can create a folder
  '           within a store but it cannot create a store.
  ' ErrMsg    The reason for any failure
  ' Sep       If the separator for FldrName is not "\", used to specify the
  '           actual separator.

  Dim FldrChld As Outlook.Folder
  Dim FldrCrnt As Outlook.Folder
  Dim FldrNameCrnt As String
  Dim FldrNameParts() As String
  Dim InxP As Long
  Dim NoError As Boolean

  If FldrName = "" Then
    ErrMsg = "No folder name provided"
    Set GetFldrRef = Nothing
  End If

  FldrNameParts = Split(FldrName, Sep)

  Set FldrCrnt = Nothing
  On Error Resume Next
  Set FldrCrnt = AppOut.Session.Folders(FldrNameParts(0))
  On Error GoTo 0
  If FldrCrnt Is Nothing Then
    ' Store name not recognised
    Debug.Print FldrNameParts(0) & " is not recognised as a store"
    Debug.Assert False     ' Fatal error
    Set GetFldrRef = Nothing
    Exit Function
  End If
  FldrNameCrnt = FldrNameParts(0)

  NoError = True
  For InxP = 1 To UBound(FldrNameParts)
  Set FldrChld = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set FldrChld = FldrCrnt.Folders(FldrNameParts(InxP))
    On Error GoTo 0
    If FldrChld Is Nothing Then
      If Not Create Then
        ' Sub-folder name not recognised but folder FldrName must exist
        ErrMsg = """" & FldrNameParts(InxP) & """ is not recognised as a " & _
                 "folder within " & FldrNameCrnt
        Debug.Assert False    ' Fatal error
        Set GetFldrRef = Nothing
        Exit Function
      Else
        NoError = False
        Exit For
      End If
    End If
    Set FldrCrnt = FldrChld
    FldrNameCrnt = FldrNameCrnt & Sep & FldrNameParts(InxP)
    Set FldrChld = Nothing
  Next

  If NoError Then
    ' Entire FldrName successfully converted to folder reference
    ErrMsg = ""
    Set GetFldrRef = FldrCrnt
    Exit Function
  End If

  ' FldrCrnt is a existing folder within Outlook named FldrNameCrnt
  ' Subfolder FldrNameParts(InxP) does not exist within FldrCrnt
  ' Create Subfolder FldrNameParts(InxP) and any children

  For InxP = InxP To UBound(FldrNameParts)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set FldrChld = FldrCrnt.Folders.Add(FldrNameParts(InxP))
    On Error GoTo 0
    If FldrChld Is Nothing Then
      ' Attempt to create sub-folder failed
      ErrMsg = """" & FldrNameParts(InxP) & """ cannot be created as a " & _
               "sub-folder within folder " & FldrNameCrnt
      Debug.Assert False    ' Fatal error
      Set GetFldrRef = Nothing
      Exit Function
    End If
    Set FldrCrnt = FldrChld
    FldrNameCrnt = FldrNameCrnt & Sep & FldrNameParts(InxP)
    Set FldrChld = Nothing
  Next

  Set GetFldrRef = FldrCrnt

End Function
```

You can include the above function in PERSONAL.XLSB, a separate module within your workbook or the same module as the other code.

The following code belongs in a module within your workbook:

*Code moved to second answer because size limit exceeded.*

You will notice that I make heavy use of `Debug.Print` to help debug my code.  Some `Debug.Print`s are commented out since I have fully debugged their bit of the code.  Other `Debug.Print`s are still active because I am still working on the code.  I also tend to plant `Debug.Assert False` at the top of every branch through the code.  This stops execution the first time the branch is taken.  Once I have checked the branch executes as I wish, I comment it out.  An active `Debug.Assert False` tells me I have not tested a branch.

You will need to amend function `GetOtherParty`.  The other party is the sender if you are the receiver and the recipients if you are the sender.  I have two email addresses.  This routine checks to see if I am the sender or the receiver and gets the name of the other party.  You will have to amend this for your email address or addresses.

The first macro is `TidyPhase1`.  This searches through every folder of every store in your Outlook installation and write a row to worksheet “Emails” for every email”.  It creates columns “Status”, “Other party”, “Folder”, “Count” and “Received Time”.  I will explain “Status” and “Count” later.  If other party is “SmithJohn@gmail.com” and folder in “abc\def\ghi”, you have sent an email to or received an email from John Smith which is in folder “abc\def\ghi”.  Originally I had a column indicating if an email was sent or received.  I found this to be a nuisance for the next macro and its value was not obvious.  I included the received time so I could locate the email in Outlook if I did not understand a row.  If you decide to add a column for another property please use a constant for the column number, as I have, and update constant `ColEmailsSortLast` as appropriate.

Note that `TidyPhase1` does not use recursion.  Recursion is a very convenient technique but it is slow.  I use a Collection to build my own stack although it is not a LIFO stack.  I will explain further if necessary.

The next macro is `TidyPhase2`.  This merges rows for the same other party and folder.  The column “Count” identifies the number of source rows for a merged row.  At the end of this macro, worksheet “Emails” will be sequenced by other party and will contain rows like:

```
Status   Other party          Folder  Count  Received
         SmithJohn@gmail.com  FolderA     2
         SmithJohn@gmail.com  FolderB    10
         SmithJohn@gmail.com  FolderC     1  12/8/2019 20:13
```

There is only one email for John in FolderC so the date/time received in display in your local format. I found having a date useful in investigating emails that are misplaced.  If FolderB is the correct folder, type values into the Status column to give:

```
Status   Other party          Folder  Count  Received
move     SmithJohn@gmail.com  FolderA     2
dest     SmithJohn@gmail.com  FolderB    10
move     SmithJohn@gmail.com  FolderC     1  12/8/2019 20:13
```

The macro `HandleDestAndMove` will move John’s emails from FolderA and FolderC to FolderB.  When the macro has finished, the worksheet will look like:

```
Status   Other party          Folder  Count  Received
dest     SmithJohn@gmail.com  FolderB    13
```

If the correct folder is FolderD, add a row to give:

```
Status   Other party          Folder  Count  Received
move     SmithJohn@gmail.com  FolderA     2
move     SmithJohn@gmail.com  FolderB    10
move     SmithJohn@gmail.com  FolderC     1  12/8/2019 20:13
dest     SmithJohn@gmail.com  FolderD
```

When the macro has finished, the worksheet will look like:

```
Status   Other party          Folder  Count  Received
dest     SmithJohn@gmail.com  FolderD    13
```

I can already see ways of improving my macros but have decided to give you something now rather than wait until I have improved them since those improvements may not be important to you.

To summarise:

- Macro `TidyPhase1` shows how to search every folder of every store for email.
- Macro `HandleDestAndMove` shows how to convert a folder name to a folder reference and how to move an email from one folder to another.

Come back with questions if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Code moved from first answer because of size limit:

```
Option Explicit

  ' Requires reference to "Microsoft Outlook n.nn Object Library" where "n.nn"
  ' depends on the version of Outlook used.

  Const ColEmailsSortFirst As Long = 1
  Const ColEmailsStatus As Long = 1
  Const ColEmailsOtherParty As Long = 2
  Const ColEmailsFldrName As Long = 3
  Const ColEmailsCount As Long = 4
  Const ColEmailsReceivedTime As Long = 5
  Const ColEmailsSortLast As Long = 5
Sub TidyPhase1()

  ' * Accesses Outlook and copies other party, folder and received time
  '   of every email to worksheet "Emails".
  ' * If the sender email address is not one of my addresses, it is
  '   used to identify the other party.  Otherwise the macro uses Recipients
  '   to build the other party.

  Dim AppOut As Outlook.Application
  Dim EmailAddressOtherParty As String
  Dim FldrsToCheck As Collection
  Dim FldrCrnt As Outlook.Folder
  Dim FldrNameCrnt As String
  Dim InxA As Long
  Dim InxF As Long
  Dim InxI As Long
  'Dim InxR As Long
  Dim InxS As Long
  Dim RowEmailsCrnt As Long
  Dim WshtEmails As Worksheet

  Load frmProgress
  With frmProgress
    .Caption = "Tidy Outlook Phase 1"
    .lblMsg.Caption = "Opening Outlook if not already open"
    .lblFldr.Caption = ""
    .lblFldrCrnt.Caption = ""
    .lblFldrOf.Caption = ""
    .lblFldrMax.Caption = ""
    .lblItem.Caption = ""
    .lblItemCrnt.Caption = ""
    .lblItemOf.Caption = ""
    .lblItemMax.Caption = ""
    .Show vbModeless
  End With
  DoEvents

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Set WshtEmails = Worksheets("Emails")
  With WshtEmails
    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete
    WshtEmails.Cells(1, ColEmailsStatus).Value = "Status"
    WshtEmails.Cells(1, ColEmailsOtherParty).Value = "Other party"
    WshtEmails.Cells(1, ColEmailsFldrName).Value = "Folder"
    WshtEmails.Cells(1, ColEmailsCount).Value = "Count"
    WshtEmails.Cells(1, ColEmailsReceivedTime).Value = "Received"
  End With

  Set AppOut = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

  With frmProgress
    .lblMsg.Caption = "Preparing to search Outlook folders for emails"
    .lblFldr.Caption = "Folders to check"
    .lblFldrMax.Caption = "0"
  End With
  DoEvents

  Set FldrsToCheck = New Collection

  With AppOut
    With .Session
      ' Initialise FldrsToCheck with reference to and name of
      ' every accessible store
      For InxS = 1 To .Folders.Count
        FldrsToCheck.Add VBA.Array(.Folders(InxS), .Folders(InxS).Name)
        With frmProgress
          .lblFldrMax.Caption = FldrsToCheck.Count
        End With
        DoEvents
      Next
    End With
  End With

  ' Process all folders
  With frmProgress
    .lblMsg.Caption = "Checking folders"
    .lblFldr.Caption = "Folders to check"
    .lblFldrMax.Caption = FldrsToCheck.Count
  End With
  DoEvents
  RowEmailsCrnt = 2
  Do While FldrsToCheck.Count > 0
    ' Extract next folder to process and delete it
    Set FldrCrnt = FldrsToCheck(1)(0)
    FldrNameCrnt = FldrsToCheck(1)(1)
    Call FldrsToCheck.Remove(1)
    'Debug.Print FldrCrnt.Name & " " & FldrNameCrnt & " " & FldrCrnt.Items.Count
    With FldrCrnt
      If .Folders.Count > 0 Then
        ' Folder contains sub-folders
        ' Add sub-folders to FldrsToCheck
        For InxF = 1 To .Folders.Count
          FldrsToCheck.Add VBA.Array(.Folders(InxF), _
                                     FldrNameCrnt & "\" & .Folders(InxF).Name)
          With frmProgress
           .lblFldrMax.Caption = FldrsToCheck.Count
          End With
          DoEvents
        Next
      End If
      If .Items.Count > 0 Then
        ' Folder contains items
        If .DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
          ' Folder could contains MailItems
          With frmProgress
           .lblItem.Caption = "Item within current folder"
           .lblItemCrnt.Caption = "0"
           .lblItemOf.Caption = "of"
           .lblItemMax.Caption = FldrCrnt.Items.Count
          End With
          DoEvents
          ' Output details of all mail items to worksheet "Emails"
          For InxI = 1 To .Items.Count
            With .Items(InxI)
              If .Class = olMail Then
                WshtEmails.Cells(RowEmailsCrnt, ColEmailsOtherParty).Value = _
                                                    GetOtherParty(FldrCrnt.Items(InxI))
                WshtEmails.Cells(RowEmailsCrnt, ColEmailsFldrName).Value = FldrNameCrnt
                WshtEmails.Cells(RowEmailsCrnt, ColEmailsCount).Value = 1
                WshtEmails.Cells(RowEmailsCrnt, ColEmailsReceivedTime).Value = .ReceivedTime
                RowEmailsCrnt = RowEmailsCrnt + 1
              End If
            End With
            With frmProgress
             .lblItemCrnt.Caption = InxI
            End With
          Next InxI
        End If  ' .DefaultItemType = olMailItem
      End If  ' .Items.Count > 0
    End With  ' FldrCrnt
    With frmProgress
      .lblFldrMax.Caption = FldrsToCheck.Count
      .lblItem.Caption = ""
      .lblItemCrnt.Caption = ""
      .lblItemOf.Caption = ""
      .lblItemMax.Caption = ""
    End With
    DoEvents
  Loop

  With frmProgress
    .lblMsg.Caption = "Closing Outlook if not opened by another process"
  End With
  DoEvents

  AppOut.Quit

  Set AppOut = Nothing
  Unload frmProgress

  With WshtEmails
    .Columns.AutoFit
    .Rows.AutoFit
    .Cells.VerticalAlignment = xlTop
  End With

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Sub TidyPhase2()

  ' 1. Sorts worksheet "Emails" by Other party.
  ' 2. Rows for the same Other party and Folder are combined.

  Dim RngSortAll As Range
  Dim RngSortCol As Range
  Dim RowEmailsCrnt As Long
  Dim RowEmailsLast As Long
  Dim WshtEmails As Worksheet

  Load frmProgress
  With frmProgress
    .Caption = "Tidy Outlook Phase 2"
    .lblMsg.Caption = "Sorting worksheet by 'Other Party'"
    .lblFldr.Caption = ""
    .lblFldrCrnt.Caption = ""
    .lblFldrOf.Caption = ""
    .lblFldrMax.Caption = ""
    .lblItem.Caption = ""
    .lblItemCrnt.Caption = ""
    .lblItemOf.Caption = ""
    .lblItemMax.Caption = ""
    .Show vbModeless
  End With
  DoEvents

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Set WshtEmails = Worksheets("Emails")

  With WshtEmails

    RowEmailsLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColEmailsCount).End(xlUp).Row
    Set RngSortAll = .Range(.Cells(1, ColEmailsSortFirst), _
                            .Cells(RowEmailsLast, ColEmailsSortLast))
    Set RngSortCol = .Range(.Cells(2, ColEmailsOtherParty), _
                            .Cells(RowEmailsLast, ColEmailsOtherParty))

    With .Sort
      .SortFields.Clear
      .SortFields.Add Key:=RngSortCol, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                      Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
      .SetRange RngSortAll
      .Header = xlYes
      .MatchCase = False
      .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
      .SortMethod = xlPinYin
      .Apply
    End With

  End With  ' WshtEmails

  With frmProgress
    .Caption = "Tidy Outlook Phase 2"
    .lblMsg.Caption = "Merging rows for same 'Other Party' and 'Folder'"
    .lblItemCrnt.Caption = "0"
    .lblItemOf.Caption = "of"
    .lblItemMax.Caption = RowEmailsLast
  End With
  DoEvents

  With Worksheets("Emails")
    RowEmailsCrnt = 2

    Do While RowEmailsCrnt <= RowEmailsLast
      If (.Cells(RowEmailsCrnt, ColEmailsOtherParty).Value = _
          .Cells(RowEmailsCrnt - 1, ColEmailsOtherParty).Value) And _
         (.Cells(RowEmailsCrnt, ColEmailsFldrName).Value = _
          .Cells(RowEmailsCrnt - 1, ColEmailsFldrName).Value) Then
        .Cells(RowEmailsCrnt - 1, ColEmailsCount).Value = _
                      .Cells(RowEmailsCrnt - 1, ColEmailsCount).Value + _
                      .Cells(RowEmailsCrnt, ColEmailsCount).Value
        .Cells(RowEmailsCrnt - 1, ColEmailsReceivedTime).Value = ""
        .Rows(RowEmailsCrnt).Delete
        RowEmailsLast = RowEmailsLast - 1
        frmProgress.lblItemMax.Caption = RowEmailsLast
      Else
        RowEmailsCrnt = RowEmailsCrnt + 1
        frmProgress.lblItemCrnt.Caption = RowEmailsCrnt
      End If
      DoEvents
    Loop

  End With

  Unload frmProgress

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Function GetOtherParty(ItemCrnt As Outlook.MailItem) As String

  ' If the sender is one of my email addresses, return recipient.
  ' Otherwise return sender.

  Dim InxR As Long
  Dim OtherParty As String
  Dim EmailIn As Boolean

  With ItemCrnt

    EmailIn = True  ' Assume incoming email until find otherwise
    OtherParty = .SenderEmailAddress
    If OtherParty = " tonydallimore@myisp.com" Then
      EmailIn = False
    ElseIf OtherParty = "tonydallimore@gmail.com" Then
      EmailIn = False
    End If

    If Not EmailIn Then
      ' Create OtherParty from Recipients
      OtherParty = .Recipients(1).Address
        For InxR = 2 To .Recipients.Count
          OtherParty = OtherParty & vbLf & .Recipients(InxR).Address
        Next
     End If

   End With

  GetOtherParty = OtherParty

End Function
Sub HandleDestAndMove()

  ' Before calling this routine:
  '  1. Find one or more rows with Other Party = "Xxxx" and with Folder not
  '     correct for Other Party Xxxx.  Set Status of these rows to "Move".
  '  2. Find the row with Other Party = "Xxxx" and with Folder correct
  '     for Other Party Xxxx.  Set Status of this row to "Dest".
  '  3. If no suitable dest row exists, because no emails for the Other Party
  '     are present in the dest folder, create such a row.  If this folder
  '     does not exist within Outlook, this routine will create it.

  ' Finds matching Dest and Move rows in worksheet "Email" and move emails
  ' from the folders identified in Move rows to the folder identified in the
  ' matching Dest row.

  ' 1. Look for "Dest" in column Status.  Record Other Party And Folder.
  ' 2. Find or create dest folder within Outlook.
  ' 3. Find a row with "Move" in column Status and the same Other Party
  '    as the dest row.
  ' 4. Find the move folder within Outlook.
  ' 5  Move all emails for the Other Party from the move folder to the
  '    dest folder.
  ' 6  Reduce count of move row and increase count of dest row
  ' 7  Repeat steps 3 to 6 until all move rows for the Other Party have
  '    been priocessed.
  ' 8  Repeat steps 1 to 7 until all dest row have been processed.
  ' 9  Delete all move rows with count of 0

  Dim AppOut As Outlook.Application
  Dim CountDest As Long
  Dim ErrMsg As String
  Dim FldrDest As Outlook.Folder
  Dim FldrDestName As String
  Dim FldrSrc As Outlook.Folder
  Dim FldrSrcName As String
  Dim InxI As Long
  Dim InxR As Long
  'Dim MatchFound As Boolean
  Dim NumFldrsDestPrcd As Long       ' Number of destination folders processed so far
  Dim NumFldrsDestTtl As Long        ' Total number of destination folders
  Dim NumItemsToMoveCrnt As Long     ' Number of emails in current move fldr according to worksheet
  Dim NumItemsToMovePrcd As Long     ' Actual number of emails moved
  Dim NumItemsToMoveTtl As Long      ' Total number of emails to move according to worksheet
  Dim OtherPartyDest As String
  Dim OtherPartyEmail As String
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RowEmailsCrnt As Long
  Dim RowEmailsDestOrig As Long
  Dim RowEmailsDestCrnt As Long
  Dim RowEmailsMoveOrig As Long
  Dim RowEmailsMoveCrnt As Long
  Dim WshtEmails As Worksheet

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Load frmProgress
  With frmProgress
    .Caption = "Handle moves"
    .lblMsg.Caption = "Accessing work load"
    .lblFldr.Caption = "Destination folders"
    .lblFldrCrnt.Caption = ""
    .lblFldrOf.Caption = ""
    .lblFldrMax.Caption = "0"
    .lblItem.Caption = "Total mail items to move"
    .lblItemCrnt.Caption = ""
    .lblItemOf.Caption = ""
    .lblItemMax.Caption = "0"
    .Show vbModeless
  End With
  DoEvents

  Set WshtEmails = Worksheets("Emails")

  NumFldrsDestTtl = 0
  NumItemsToMoveTtl = 0

  RowEmailsCrnt = 1

  'Count number of occurrences of "dest" and "move" in status column
  With WshtEmails
    ' Find first value in status column
    Set Rng = .Columns(ColEmailsStatus).Find( _
                What:="*", After:=.Cells(RowEmailsCrnt, ColEmailsStatus), _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      Debug.Assert False
      Call MsgBox("No rows found with anything in status column", vbOKOnly)
      Unload frmProgress
      Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Process value just found in status column then find next value.
    ' Loop until next value is on row 1.
    Do While True
      If LCase(.Cells(Rng.Row, ColEmailsStatus).Value) = "dest" Then
        NumFldrsDestTtl = NumFldrsDestTtl + 1
        frmProgress.lblFldrMax.Caption = NumFldrsDestTtl
      ElseIf LCase(.Cells(Rng.Row, ColEmailsStatus).Value) = "move" Then
        If IsNumeric(.Cells(Rng.Row, ColEmailsCount).Value) Then
          NumItemsToMoveTtl = NumItemsToMoveTtl + .Cells(Rng.Row, ColEmailsCount).Value
          frmProgress.lblItemMax.Caption = NumItemsToMoveTtl
        Else
          .Cells(Rng.Row, ColEmailsCount).Value = 0
        End If
      End If
      DoEvents
      Set Rng = .Columns(ColEmailsStatus).FindNext(Rng)
      If Rng.Row = 1 Then
        ' Have looped back to top row
        Exit Do
      End If
    Loop
  End With  ' WshtEmails

  If NumFldrsDestTtl = 0 Or NumItemsToMoveTtl = 0 Then
    Debug.Assert False
    Call MsgBox("Nothing found to do", vbOKOnly)
    Unload frmProgress
    Exit Sub
   End If

  With frmProgress
    .lblMsg.Caption = "Opening Outlook if not already open"
  End With
  DoEvents

  ' There can only be one instance of Outlook open.  If Outlook is already
  ' open, CreateObject will create a link to that instance. If the user opens
  ' and closes Outlook while this macro is running, it will close the instance
  ' this macro is using.
  Set AppOut = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

  With frmProgress
    .lblMsg.Caption = "Moving emails to correct folder"
    .lblFldrCrnt.Caption = "0"
    .lblFldrOf.Caption = "of"
    .lblItemCrnt.Caption = "0"
    .lblItemOf.Caption = "of"
  End With
  DoEvents

  RowEmailsDestOrig = 0   ' No dest row found
  RowEmailsDestCrnt = 1   ' Start row for first search for dest row

  ' This outer loop find first occurence of "dest" in status column. When
  ' inner loop has finished processing move rows, the next dest row is found.
  ' This continues until the first dest row is found again.
  Do While True

    With WshtEmails

      Set Rng = .Columns(ColEmailsStatus).Find( _
                  What:="dest", After:=.Cells(RowEmailsDestCrnt, ColEmailsStatus), _
                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
      If Rng Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Assert False
        Call MsgBox("No row found with 'Dest' in status column", vbOKOnly)
        Exit Sub
      End If
      If RowEmailsDestOrig = 0 Then
        ' This is first dest row found.  When it is found again, all dest rows
        ' have been processed.
        'Debug.Assert False
        RowEmailsDestOrig = Rng.Row
      ElseIf RowEmailsDestOrig = Rng.Row Then
        ' Have looped back to first dest row
        'Debug.Assert False
        Exit Do
      End If
      RowEmailsDestCrnt = Rng.Row
      OtherPartyDest = .Cells(RowEmailsDestCrnt, ColEmailsOtherParty).Value
      FldrDestName = .Cells(RowEmailsDestCrnt, ColEmailsFldrName).Value
      If .Cells(RowEmailsDestCrnt, ColEmailsCount).Value = "" Then
        'Debug.Assert False
        .Cells(RowEmailsDestCrnt, ColEmailsCount).Value = 0
      End If
      CountDest = .Cells(RowEmailsDestCrnt, ColEmailsCount).Value
      ' Count column will be increased for each email moves into dest fldr.
    End With  ' WshtEmails

    Debug.Print "Dest " & OtherPartyDest & " " & RowEmailsDestCrnt
    Debug.Print "  " & FldrDestName
    Debug.Print "  CountDest " & CountDest
    Set FldrDest = GetFldrRef(AppOut, FldrDestName, True, ErrMsg)
    If ErrMsg <> "" Then
      Debug.Print "  GetFldrRef: " & ErrMsg
    Else
      Debug.Print "  GetFldrRef: " & FldrDest.Name
    End If

    RowEmailsMoveOrig = 0                   ' No move row found
    RowEmailsMoveCrnt = RowEmailsDestCrnt   ' Start row for search for move row

    ' This inner loop find first occurence of "move" in status column after the
    ' dest row. When processing of the move row has finished, the next move row
    ' is found. This continues until the first move row is found again.
    Do While True

      With WshtEmails

        Set Rng = .Columns(ColEmailsStatus).Find( _
                    What:="move", After:=.Cells(RowEmailsMoveCrnt, ColEmailsStatus), _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Rng Is Nothing Then
          'Debug.Assert False
          Call MsgBox("No rows found with 'Move' in status column", vbOKOnly)
          Exit Do
        End If
      End With

      RowEmailsMoveCrnt = Rng.Row
      If RowEmailsMoveOrig = 0 Then
        ' This is first move row found after dest row.  When it is found again,
        ' all move rows have been checked.
        'Debug.Assert False
        RowEmailsMoveOrig = RowEmailsMoveCrnt
      ElseIf RowEmailsMoveOrig = RowEmailsMoveCrnt Then
        ' Have looped back to first move row
        'Debug.Assert False
        Exit Do
      End If

      ' Have a new move row but may not be for dest row

      If OtherPartyDest = WshtEmails.Cells(RowEmailsMoveCrnt, ColEmailsOtherParty).Value Then
        ' Have move row for current dest row
        'Debug.Assert False
        FldrSrcName = WshtEmails.Cells(RowEmailsMoveCrnt, ColEmailsFldrName).Value
        NumItemsToMoveCrnt = WshtEmails.Cells(RowEmailsMoveCrnt, ColEmailsCount).Value
        Debug.Print "  Move " & RowEmailsMoveCrnt & " " & FldrSrcName

        Set FldrSrc = GetFldrRef(AppOut, FldrSrcName, False, ErrMsg)
        If ErrMsg <> "" Then
          Debug.Print "    GetFldrRef: " & ErrMsg
          Debug.Assert False
        Else
          Debug.Print "    FldrSrc.Name: " & FldrSrc.Name
        End If

        ' Have found move row for current dest row
        ' Move all MailItems for other party to dest fldr
        For InxI = FldrSrc.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
          If OtherPartyDest = GetOtherParty(FldrSrc.Items(InxI)) Then
            Debug.Print "    Match " & FldrSrc.Items(InxI).ReceivedTime
            FldrSrc.Items(InxI).Move FldrDest
            NumItemsToMovePrcd = NumItemsToMovePrcd + 1
            CountDest = CountDest + 1
            With frmProgress
              .lblItemCrnt.Caption = NumItemsToMovePrcd
            End With
            DoEvents
            NumItemsToMoveCrnt = NumItemsToMoveCrnt - 1
          Else
            'Debug.Print "NonMt " & FldrSrc.Items(InxI).ReceivedTime
          End If
        Next InxI
        Debug.Print "    CountDest " & CountDest
        WshtEmails.Cells(RowEmailsMoveCrnt, ColEmailsCount).Value = NumItemsToMoveCrnt
        WshtEmails.Cells(RowEmailsMoveCrnt, ColEmailsReceivedTime).Value = ""
        WshtEmails.Cells(RowEmailsDestCrnt, ColEmailsCount).Value = CountDest
        Debug.Print "    NumItemsToMoveCrnt " & NumItemsToMoveCrnt
        If NumItemsToMoveCrnt <> 0 Then
          'Debug.Assert False
          ' The actual number of emails found did not match the count in the worksheet
          ' Adjust display counts
          NumItemsToMoveTtl = NumItemsToMoveTtl - NumItemsToMoveCrnt
          With frmProgress
            .lblItemMax.Caption = NumItemsToMoveTtl
          End With
          DoEvents
        End If

      End If  ' move row for current dest row

    Loop  ' for all move rows

    NumFldrsDestPrcd = NumFldrsDestPrcd + 1
    Debug.Print "NumFldrsDestPrcd " & NumFldrsDestPrcd
    With frmProgress
      .lblFldrCrnt.Caption = NumFldrsDestPrcd
    End With
    DoEvents

  Loop  ' for all dest rows

  With frmProgress
    .lblMsg.Caption = "Closing Outlook if not opened by another process"
  End With
  DoEvents

  AppOut.Quit
  Set AppOut = Nothing

  With frmProgress
    .lblMsg.Caption = "Deleting move rows with a count of zero"
    .lblFldr.Caption = ""
    .lblFldrCrnt.Caption = ""
    .lblFldrOf.Caption = ""
    .lblFldrMax.Caption = ""
    .lblItem.Caption = "Move rows deleted"
    .lblItemCrnt.Caption = "0"
    .lblItemOf.Caption = ""
    .lblItemMax.Caption = ""
  End With
  DoEvents

  With WshtEmails

    RowEmailsMoveCrnt = 1

    Do While True  ' Loop until no move rows with a count of 0

      Set Rng = .Columns(ColEmailsStatus).Find( _
                  What:="move", After:=.Cells(RowEmailsMoveCrnt, ColEmailsStatus), _
                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

      If Rng Is Nothing Then
        'Debug.Assert False
        ' All move row deleted
        Exit Do
      End If

      RowEmailsMoveCrnt = Rng.Row
      RowEmailsMoveOrig = RowEmailsMoveCrnt

      Do While True
        If WshtEmails.Cells(RowEmailsMoveCrnt, ColEmailsCount).Value = 0 Then
          ' This row is to be deleted
          .Rows(RowEmailsMoveCrnt).Delete
          RowEmailsMoveCrnt = RowEmailsMoveCrnt - 1
          RowEmailsMoveOrig = 0
          Exit Do
        End If
        Set Rng = .Columns(ColEmailsStatus).Find(Rng)
        RowEmailsMoveCrnt = Rng.Row
        If RowEmailsMoveOrig = RowEmailsMoveCrnt Then
          ' Have move rows but none with a count of 0
          Exit Do
        End If
      Loop  ' until row deleted or no row to delete

      If RowEmailsMoveOrig = RowEmailsMoveCrnt Then
        ' There are move rows but none with a count of 0
        Exit Do
      End If

    Loop  ' until no move rows with a count of 0

  End With

  Unload frmProgress

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```