# How to reference a folder in a specified account?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying output a list of everyone that has emailed me, and the count of emails they sent.

I have two email accounts set up on Outlook (account A and account B). The below VBA outputs a count of users from the inbox folder for account A.

Is there a way to retrieve this data from a folder called 'Done' for Account B?

```vb
Sub CountInboxEmailsbySender()
    Dim objDictionary As Object
    Dim objInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim i As Long
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strSender As String
    Dim objExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim objExcelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objExcelWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim varSenders As Variant
    Dim varItemCounts As Variant
    Dim nLastRow As Integer
 
    Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set objInbox = Outlook.Application.Session.Accounts.Item("edr.hub@bt.com")
    
    For i = objInbox.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        If objInbox.Items(i).Class = olMail Then
           Set objMail = objInbox.Items(i)
           strSender = objMail.SenderEmailAddress
 
           If objDictionary.Exists(strSender) Then
              objDictionary.Item(strSender) = objDictionary.Item(strSender) + 1
           Else
              objDictionary.Add strSender, 1
           End If
        End If
    Next

    Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcelApp.Visible = True
    Set objExcelWorkbook = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Add
    Set objExcelWorksheet = objExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1)
 
    With objExcelWorksheet
         .Cells(1, 1) = "Sender"
         .Cells(1, 2) = "Count"
    End With
 
    varSenders = objDictionary.Keys
    varItemCounts = objDictionary.Items
 
    For i = LBound(varSenders) To UBound(varSenders)
        nLastRow = objExcelWorksheet.Range("A" & objExcelWorksheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        With objExcelWorksheet
             .Cells(nLastRow, 1) = varSenders(i)
             .Cells(nLastRow, 2) = varItemCounts(i)
        End With
    Next
 
    objExcelWorksheet.Columns("A:B").AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: 2nd answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43613459/select-outlook-folder-with-excel-vba) should help you.